# Valuation theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

what is the the natural, non-trivial valuation $\mathbb{v}$ in a field F? This term appeared in some articles about $\mathbb{R}$-places that I was studying. I do have some small background in valuation theory, but I don't know what "natural valuation" stands for.

Comment: It depends on $F$ and the context. On $\Bbb{Q}_p$ there is only one discrete valuation, on $\Bbb{R}$ the usual absolute value is said natural for obvious reasons, on a finitely generated transcendental extension $L/k$ the (discrete) valuations being trivial on $k$ are natural.

Comment: It would help if you specify the field $F$. If it is a well-known field we probably can tell you the natural, non-trivial valuation in that field.

Comment: If the field is ordered, then the "natural valuation" is that whose valuation ring is the set of elements bounded by integers.

Answer (score 0):

There is not "the" natural non-trivial (absolute value) valuation  on a field $F$. A finite field only has the trivial valuation, for example, given by $|a|=1$ for all $a\neq 0$. The field $\Bbb Q$ has a $p$-adic valuation $|\cdot |_{p}$ for every prime $p$ and also the usual absolute valuation $|\cdot |_{\infty}$. The first is non-Archimedean, the second one is Archimedian. The Theorem of Ostrowski says that every non-trivial valuation on $\Bbb Q$ is equivalent to either $|\cdot |_{p}$ or $|\cdot |_{\infty}$.